# Chooser thumbnail link expiration

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the chooser to get "direct" links (which according to the documentation expire after 4 hours).

In addition to the direct link to the file, dropbox also returns an icon URL and several thumbnail Urls.

Do the thumbnail URL's expire as well or are they good forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the thumbnails expire at the same time as the direct link (after 4 hours).

Comment: What about if not using the direct link? ie. if you use the Preview chooser api option instead?
Seems like the icons are expiring, but that's not mentioned in the Dropbox Chooser documentation.